# Android simple HTTP Get

Tags: android, http

I got a website which just response with "true"
With my app I need to open that website and just get back that response.
I tried for a few hours to do that with some http GET methods but nothing worked (not even plain copying of tutorials of that).

I just need to get the reponse of the website (in this case the word "true") and put it into a textview. But how to do that? I always fail at the line:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

And I get errors like

```
 Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

I tried it on Emulator and 3 Smartphones which are in the wlan and have internet access.
The app has also permissions to access internet and network.

I need some help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library to make things easier. [Android Async Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) works well.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Your problem here is that you are trying to do some network request inside the UI thread of your application; which is protected by the framework.

If you are very new to Android, I suggest you to read the following article about AsyncTask : [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)